# Why my type number value gets stored as a string in Firestore?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I honestly do not know why is not working, it doesn't even make sense and it was working before maybe you can spot something I can't.

I'm updating some data to Firebase with a type number but is getting stored as a string even though I'm using an input type number but it doesn't seem to be working for some reason here's the code:

```
//Firebase set
const [precio, setPrecio] = useState();
const register = (e) => {
       e.preventDefault();
       const docRef = db.collection('productos_AIB').doc(docId);

       docRef.get().then((doc) => {

           if (doc.exists) 
           {
               window.alert("Ya existe ese producto")
           }
           else {
               
               docRef.set({
                   descripcion: descripcion,
                   tipo: tipo,
                   grado: grado,
                   precio: parseFloat(precio).toFixed(2),
                   cantidad: cantidad,
                   necesita: necesita,
                   id: docRef.id
           }).then((r) => {
               window.alert("Producto agregado")
           })}
   })
}

//Input
<input 
onChange = {(e) => {setPrecio(e.target.valueAsNumber);}}
type = 'number'
pattern = "[0-9]*"
requiredplaceholder="Precio"
/>
```

if you require something else let me know, IDK why it stopped working maybe I changed something without even noticing but I can't spot the error.

**UPDATE** forgot to add a picture of how it looks in Firestore:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, the value of "precio" comes from a user input, which most likely it's a literal string, rather than a number. So `toFixed()` won't provide what you're expecting. To solve this, you should change the following line of code:

```
precio: parseFloat(precio).toFixed(2),
```

Into:

```
precio: parseFloat(parseFloat(precio).toFixed(2)),
```

In this way, you'll be able to write a number and **not** a string into Firestore.

Comment: well, that partially worked did a small test registering an object with price of 5 and it stored as a number yes but it didn't add the 2 decimals. Any suggestions ? it just stored as 5 instead of 5.00

Comment: another question: Why does it stores as an string? I have the input as a "valueAsNumber" and the type is "number" as well.

Comment: Because the input is always a string, no matter what the type you are setting.